# Custom routing in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I've been trying to understand how to generate dynamic Flask URLs. I've read the docs and several example, but can't figure out why this code doesn't work:

```
path = 'foo'
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['POST'])
def index(path=None):
    # do some stuff...
    return flask.render_template('index.html', path=path)
```

I'd expect my index.html template to be served to `/foo`, but it is not. I get a build error. What am I missing?

If I use a fixed path, like `/bar`, everything works without issue.

`@app.route('/bar', methods=['POST'])`

Comment: You say that you "get a build error". Please update your question and post the entire stack trace, along with the code that was run that caused the build error to occur.

Comment: Post your template.  I get build errors when I try to build a url with `url_for` and flask tries to build a url for an endpoint that I haven't registered on the app.

Comment: As for creating a dynamic url, you've got it. Setting `path = 'foo'` is superflous, though.  It looks like you're expecting `'foo'` to be passed into your view and set on your template, but if you navigate to `localhost:5000/`, flask is going to dispatch to `'/'`, missing this route entirely. Pretty sure setting the default value of `None` on `path` in your method signature is unnecessary as well, because that arg to your `index` view function will be built from the request URI.  A default value would never be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got the long and short of it already.  All you need to do is decorate your view functions using the `/<var>` syntax (or the `/<converter:var>` syntax where appropriate).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<word>', defaults={'word': 'bird'})
def word_up(word):
    return render_template('whatstheword.html', word=word)

@app.route('/files/<path:path>')
def serve_file(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_DIR'], path, as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=9017)
```

When Flask pulls a variable out of a URL for a dynamic route like you're trying to use, it'll be a unicode string in Python by default.  If you create the variable with the `<int:var>` or `<float:var>` converters, it'll be converted to the appropriate type in the app space for you.

The `<path:blah>` converter will match on a string that contains slashes (`/`), so you can pass `/blah/dee/blah` and the path variable in your view function will contain that string.  Without using the `path` converter, flask would try and dispatch your request to a view function registered on the route `/blah/dee/blah`, because the plain `<var>` is delineated by the next `/` in the uri.

So looking at my little app, the `/files/<path:path>` route would serve whatever file it could find that matched the path sent up by the user on the request.  I pulled this example from the docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

Also, dig that you can specify defaults for your variable URLs via a keyword `arg` to the `route()` decorator.

If you want, you can even access the underlying `url_map` that Werkzeug builds based on how you specify your view functions and routes in your app space. For more stuff to chew on, check out the [api docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations) on URL registrations.

Comment: /<converter:var>  How to set the boolen value in converter I tried to set bool but it's failing

Comment: '/<string:word>' I know how to use string as converter like this how to use bool converter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`add_url_rule()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule):

```
def index(path=None):
    return render_template('index.html', path=path)

path = '/foo'
app.add_url_rule(path, 'index', index)
```

You also might want to look at [blueprint objects](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#blueprint-objects) if you end up doing this alot.